# Solve the differential equation $R*C*y'(t)+y(t)=x(t)$ using Convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution, dirac-delta

I have the next differential equation: $R*C*y'(t)+y(t)=x(t)$
Where $x(t)$ is a piecewise funtion defined by:
   \begin{equation}
     \label{eq:aqui-le-mostramos-como-hacerle-la-llave-grande}
     x(t) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
   0      & \mathrm{if\ } t \le 0 \\
   \alpha & \mathrm{if\ } 0 \le t \le \tau \\
   -\frac{a}{\tau}+2\alpha     & \mathrm{if\ } \tau \le t\le 2\tau\\
         0     & \mathrm{if\ } 2\tau \le t
        \end{array}
      \right.
   \end{equation}
Where $R$,$C$,$\alpha$ and $\tau$ are constants with any value.
And I know that the convolution is given by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\lambda)h(t-\lambda)d\lambda$.

In this case $h(t)=\frac{1}{RC}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}u(t)$.

Note: $h(t)$ was obtained by solving the next differential equation using the Laplace transforms: $RCh'(t)+h(t)=\delta(t)$

So using the convolution,I have two cases simpler than the others, when $t<0$ the function x(t) is equals to zero so in this case the value of the convolution is equals to zero.

And the other case is from $0\le t<\tau$ where I consider the next integral:
\begin{equation*}
y(t)=\int_0^t\alpha\frac{1}{RC}e^{-\frac{1}{RC}(t-\lambda)}d\lambda
\end{equation*}
What after do the integration, I got to this function of t:
\begin{equation*}
y(t)=\alpha(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})
\end{equation*}

However I have problems to get the integral in the others intervals of the function.

Comment: What is the $a$ in $-(a/\tau)+2\alpha$ that appears in $\tau\leq t\leq 2\tau$ piece of $x(t)$?  Is that supposed to be related to $\alpha,\tau,t,R,C$ in some way?

Comment: Which is the original equation that you should solve?